# Parenthetical Phrase? Preposition? Hyphens?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, hyphens

I had a dialogue. with someone. They sent something like:

> **When it comes to work**, I like structure and being **detail-oriented**.

Should I call this a parenthetical phrase or preposition?

I thought hyphens should come only first what they modify, not after.

Comment: Your question is unclear. A "hyphen" is this character: [ - ].  The little dash. It does not modify anything; rather it yokes two words into a single modifier.  What do you mean by "hyphens may come only first"?  **detail-oriented** functions as an adjective. It means "oriented to details" which means "paying attention to details".

Comment: **being** is the present continuous of the verb **to be**. *Ussain Bolt likes being fast.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sentence, the first part is an example of an introductory clause.

**When it comes to work** is a dependant clause that introduces an independent clause. While the independent clause could stand on its own, the introductory clause gives it additional context.

> (Even though I thought it was futile), I tried to lift the car on my own.
>   (Although it wasn't raining), I walked down the street with an open umbrella.
>   (Because I was depressed), I didn't leave the house all day.

---

In general, hyphens are used to prevent ambiguity.

> She is a foreign-sales secretary.

Here, she is a secretary of foreign sales.

> He is a foreign sales-secretary.

Meanwhile, he is a sales secretary who is also foreign.

In compound phrases that modify something, hyphens are generally only used when the compound phrase comes before what it modifies.

> I had a half-hour session.
>   My session was a half hour.

In your example sentence, a hyphen would commonly not be used:

> I am a detail-oriented person.
>   I am a person who is detail oriented.

Comment: Yes! I thought that. Not sure why they had a hyphen on, *detail oriented*. I usually look at how they write to get proper grammar, from them; They went to a graduate school.

Comment: Ah, yes. I thought only about phrases. I did not think about clauses. Excellent!